# Is there a continuous, onto map from $[0,\infty)$ to $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Is there a continuous, onto map from $[0,\infty)$ to $\mathbb{R}$?

I have find one function , namely $f(x)=x\sin(x)$. Will it work?

Thanks

Comment: Hint for a proof: check what $x$-values the “peaks”/“troughs” of $f$ occur at, and use the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: You don't need the exact peaks/trough locations. Multiples of $\pi/2$ are fine